# Equivalent definition of <authentication-manager> in pre-namespace Spring 2.x

Tags: spring, ldap, openldap, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

I have a Spring 3 application I use:

```
  <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref='myAuthenticationProvider'/>
  </authentication-manager>
```

What would be the name space equivalent spring 2.

is because I login with my LDAP application with Spring 3 and want to implement the same method in spring 2

CODE spring-secutiy-ldap.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/app/Out*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/Login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/Out" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/**"      access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ROLE_USER" />

</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>

<!-- Server -->
<ldap-server id="ldapServer" url="ldap://${ldap.server.ip}:${ldap.server.port}/${ldap.server.root}"/>

<!-- Authenticator -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator" id="ldapBindAuthenticator">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="ldapServer"/>
    <beans:property name="userSearch" ref="userSearch"/>
</beans:bean>



<beans:bean id="userSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="ou=people"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg index="1" value="(uid={0})"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="ldapServer" />
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator" id="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="ldapServer"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg value="${ldap.springrole.rdn}"/>
    <beans:property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="${ldap.springrole.attribute}"/>
    <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="${ldap.springrole.prefix}"/>
    <beans:property name="groupSearchFilter" value="(objectClass=organizationalRole)"/>
    <beans:property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="ldapBindAuthenticator"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator"/>
    <beans:property name="userDetailsContextMapper" ref="ldapUserDetailsContextMapper"/>
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="ldapServer"/>
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean class="com.test.ladp.security.UserLdapMapper" id="ldapUserDetailsContextMapper">
    <beans:property name="template"         ref="ldapTemplate"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Exception :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.security.config.SecurityConfigurationException: No UserDetailsService registered.
    at org.springframework.security.config.UserDetailsServiceInjectionBeanPostProcessor.getUserDetailsService(UserDetailsServiceInjectionBeanPostProcessor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.config.UserDetailsServiceInjectionBeanPostProcessor.injectUserDetailsServiceIntoRememberMeServices(UserDetailsServiceInjectionBeanPostProcessor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.security.config.UserDetailsServiceInjectionBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(UserDetailsServiceInjectionBeanPostProcessor.java:36)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1330)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    ... 69 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent definition without namespace support for authentication manager should be as follows

```
<bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="ldapAuthProvider" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg ref="ldapBindAuthenticator"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator"/>
    <property name="userDetailsContextMapper" ref="ldapUserDetailsContextMapper"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails. LdapUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="userSearch" />
    <constructor-arg ref="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator" />
    <property name="userDetailsContextMapper" ref="ldapUserDetailsContextMapper"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but now I get the following error:
Caused by: org.springframework.security.config.SecurityConfigurationException: No UserDetailsService registered.

Comment: Post the configuration file you need to rewrite.

Comment: This is the file you need to adjust for Spring 2.x? I do not see any `<authentication-manager>` element.

Comment: sorry i posted the wrong file, now if the correct code, this file is in 3.x I need to pass it to spring 2.x

Comment: I edited the answer so that authentication manager uses LDAP authentication provider.

Comment: hello, thanks for the reply but still I get the error:
org.springframework.security.config.SecurityConfigurationException: No UserDetailsService registered.

Comment: Post please the whole stack trace with the exception details.